# Linux System Calls

Tags: linux, system-calls

Whats the changed over time on how Linux system calls were implemented on older (8086/88) Intel CPUS vs more modern CPU's.

Comment: They weren't implemented on 8086/88, so everything has changed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest change is the sysenter/sysexit (Intel's creation) and syscall/sysret (AMD's version) instructions on newer x86 (and Intel 64/AMD64) processors. These speed up system calls drastically compared to the interrupt method used previously. This has to do with reducing the steps the processor must go through when invoking a system call, and you can read up on them in the [Intel manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).